# How to construct QueryBuilder from JSON DSL when using Java API in ElasticSearch?

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, dsl

I'm using ElasticSearch as a search service in Spring Web project which using Transport Client to communicate with ES.

I'm wondering if there exists a method which can construct a QueryBuilder from a JSON DSL. for example, convert this bool query DSL JSON to a QueryBuilder.

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : { "match" : {"content" : "quick"},
            "should": { "match": {"content" : "lazy"}
        }
    }
}
```

I need this method because I have to receive user's bool string input from web front-side, and parse this bool string to a QueryBuilder. However it not suit to use `QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(matchQB).should(shouldQB).must_not(mustNotQB)`. Because we may need several must or non must query.

If there exist a method can construct a QueryBuilder from JSON DSL or there exists alternative solutions, it will much easier.

**PS:** I have found two method which can wrap a DSL String to a QueryBuilder for ES search.
One is **WrapperQueryBuilder**, see details here. http://javadoc.kyubu.de/elasticsearch/HEAD/org/elasticsearch/index/query/WrapperQueryBuilder.html
Another is **QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery**(String DSL).

Answer (score 35):

You can use `QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery(jsonQueryString);`

Comment: By omitting the {"query":} part in json string works charm !

Answer (score 11):

You can use `setQuery`, which can receive a json format string.

```
/**
 * Constructs a new search source builder with a raw search query.
 */
public SearchRequestBuilder setQuery(String query) {
    sourceBuilder().query(query);
    return this;
}
```

Note this: only part of the DSL is needed, the `{"query": }` part is omitted, like this:

```
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch(indices).setQuery("{\"term\": {\"id\": 1}}").execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have found two method in ES API which can wrap DSL string to QueryBuilder, one is WrapperQueryBuilder, another is QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery()

Comment: omit the {"query":} part helps me a lot, thanks again for your help.

Comment: For those of you using ES 5.0, this no longer works:

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/set-source-in-searchrequestbuilder-with-es5-0-and-java-api/66870

Comment: @GordonThompson exactly, for those using newer versions make sure to check the WrapperQuery.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth investigating [low level rest client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-low.html). With this you can do:

```java
RestClient esClient = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http")).build();
Request request = new Request("POST", "/INDEX_NAME/_doc/_search");
request.setJsonEntity(yourJsonQueryString);

Response response = esClient.performRequest(request);

String jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Answer (score 0):

With RestHighLevelClient (that uses lowLevelClient())

```
`Request request = new Request("POST", "yourURL");
    request.setJsonEntity(yourJsonDSL);
    try {
        Response response = restHighLevelClient.getLowLevelClient().performRequest(request);
        String jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        JSONObject jsonTransactionObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
                //error;
    }`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).