# How to make an Elasticsearch query with a JSON in Java?

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I am trying to make an Elasticsearch search with **Java** and **Elasticsearch**. Elastic search provides API for Java and this is cool.

The thing is, I wish to create a method in Java who receives a string (properly, a JSON containing information for searching) who reflects this HTTP call to Elasticsearch

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/geocon/_search?q=first:"Sonya"'
```

But I want this method as much general as possible.

So the question is: **is it possible to parse and translate 1:1 HTTP request to Elasticsearch with Java API?** Maybe giving to the Elasticsearch object just the JSON string as parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to do something like this:

```
String query = whatever_query...
SearchResponse response = esClient.prepareSearch(Configuration.PRIMARY_INDEX_NAME)
                    .setQuery(query)
                    .execute()
                    .actionGet();
```

Comment: how to use this rest high level client

Comment: @smackcherry could you share as one of the answers here. Would love to see how you did that?

Answer (score 4):

Check this out. Maybe this post can help you:

[How to construct QueryBuilder from JSON DSL when using Java API in ElasticSearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859921/how-to-construct-querybuilder-from-json-dsl-when-using-java-api-in-elasticsearch)