# Getting data from elasticsearch based on query using java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana

I have got the data from `Elasticsearch` index by using the below code:

```
SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest("football_sum_csv").scroll(new TimeValue(60000));
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
//    searchSourceBuilder.query(matchQuery("multi", "test"));
searchSourceBuilder.size(10000);
searchSourceBuilder.sort(FieldSortBuilder.DOC_FIELD_NAME, SortOrder.ASC);
request.source(searchSourceBuilder);
SearchResponse scrollResp = client.search(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
System.out.println(scrollResp);
```

This will return all the data from my index of `ElasticSearch`.
In here, I want to `filter` some data based on my `query`. In my case, I want to manually enter query and get results from `ElasticSearch`.

**For example:** 
This below query will return all the data as like above

```
query = {'query': {'bool': {'must': [{'match_all': {}}], 'must_not': [], 'should': []}} }
```

This below query will return all the data in the `Country` named `Spain`

```
query = {"query": {"bool": {"must": [{"match_phrase": {"countryName": "Spain"}}], "must_not": [], "should": []}}}
```

This below query will return all the data in the `os` named `Windows` and `sessionTime` between `1000` and `5000`

```
{"query": {"bool": {"must": [{"range": {"sessionTime": {"gte": 1000, "lt": 5000}}}, {"match_phrase": {"os": "Windows"}}], "must_not": [], "should": []}}}
```

In the above three queries, they perform the different operations in `ElasticSearch`. I want to use this like queries to get my data.

If I put query inside here in above `java` code,

```
searchSourceBuilder.query({"query": {"bool": {"must": [{"match_phrase": {"countryName": "Spain"}}], "must_not": [], "should": []}}});
```

It gives me an error. 
I know `Querybuilders` has lots of query options such as range, match and so on. But I want to manually enter query like the listed above and get my data from `ElasticSearch`. I don't know how to make it. Please help me with some solutions.

Comment: If that's not a typo, I believe your query should probably be a string? Something like this:
`searchSourceBuilder.query("{\"query\": {\"bool\": {\"must\": [{\"match_phrase\": {\"countryName\": \"Spain\"}}], \"must_not\": [], \"should\": []}}}");`

Comment: Yes....It is a string...How can i make it.

Comment: Can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906749/how-to-make-an-elasticsearch-query-with-a-json-in-java

Comment: @alexgids, Thank u so much..Wrapper query helped me.....

Answer (score 1):

**Found the Answer from the comment of alexgids :**
`wrapperQuery` needs to be used for passing query as `json`

```
String query = "{"bool": {"must": [{"match_phrase": {"countryName": "Spain"}}], "must_not": [], "should": []}}";
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery(query);
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder1 = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder1.query(qb);
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("index_name");
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder1);
SearchResponse scrollResp1 = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
System.out.println(scrollResp1);
```