# elasticsearch wrapper query not works with base64 encoded string

Tags: elasticsearch, base64

**elasticsearch wrapper query not works with base64 encoded string**

**ES version : 5.2.3**

To encode i have used base64:

```
char[] data = Base64Coder.encode(text.getBytes());

return data.ToString();
```

**Note**: text is the underline json query.

**query**:

```
curl -d XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/entitymaster_qa_t4/_search' -d '{
  "query" : {
    "wrapper" : {
      "query" : "W0NAMTZiN2MzYw=="
    }
  }
}'
```

**Response**:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"entitymaster_qa_t4","node":"8WVaVr9ATmaqOPDHGpNyHw","reason":{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"}}]},"status":400}
```

Comment: I don't think you can submit queries in encoded form, ES only supports indexing encoded content.

Answer (score 0):

The [wrapper query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/query-dsl-wrapper-query.html) appeared in ES 6.0 according to the docs, so if you want to use it you need to update your version. Also, the base64 string must decode into a valid query, not just a piece of data.

Comment: thank you. is there any elastic Java API that accept JSON query string to execute against the index??

Comment: I don't know, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859921/how-to-construct-querybuilder-from-json-dsl-when-using-java-api-in-elasticsearch) seems to hold your answer.